# python3 -m venv: how to specify Python point release/version?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

To create a virtual environment using `virtualenv` you can specify the Python release and point version like so:

```
virtualenv --python=python3.6 .venv
```

How can I achieve this using Python3's `venv` module (as in `python3 -m venv .newvenv`)? [According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) using `venv` is the recommended way to create virtual environments but I didn't see how I can choose a virtual environement with a specific Python version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run `venv` with whatever Python installation you want to use for the new virtual environment. For example, if you would run your Python 3.6 installation with `python3.6`, then

```
python3.6 -m venv whatever
```

would be how you create a Python 3.6 virtual environment.

Comment: Great. `python3.5 -m venv ...` works without a problem (that came with the distribution), but `python3.6 -m venv whatever` returns `Error: Command '['/home/someuser/dev/somedir/whatever/bin/python3.6', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.` - not exactly helpful, but it does create a functional Python 3.6 environment nevertheless.

Comment: 2019 and I also have the same issue. 
@mjkrause were you able to resolve the problem?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira Solution to a similar problem can be found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830431/how-to-use-python3-10-on-ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @chanp 
I've resolved the situation by using PyEnv to define envs with specific Python versions while keep it isolated from the system installation.

Answer (score 8):

I thought to add to this answer when one is using `pyenv`. In my workflow I use `pyenv` to have multiple python versions but not to manage virtualenvs. I rather have my python virtual environment in the project's root. With pyenv one can install multiple python versions by running `pyenv install 3.8.10` and after that `pyenv install 3.9.0`. When you run `pyenv versions` you should get something similar to this

```sh
  system
* 3.8.10 (set by /Users/<user>/.pyenv/version)
  3.8.10/envs/python-test.venv
  3.9.0
```

When working on a project and choosing what python version should be used in that project you can do the following.

```sh
$ mkdir my_project && cd my_project
$ pyenv global <version>
$ python --version // should be the version you set as global
$ python -m venv .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to avoid error mentioned in the comments by using the option `--without-pip`. Then after activating the venv, I installed `pip` manually with the `get-pip.py` script.