# How to use Python3.10 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-venv

I have installed Python 3.10 from `deadsnakes` on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

How to use it? `python3 --version` returns `Python 3.8.10` and `python3.10 -m venv venv` returns error (I've installed `python3-venv` as well).

Comment: Where did it install to? Find that directory, look in it to find the correct binary, make sure that directory is in your `$PATH`, then run it using the path and binary name.

Comment: have you installed `python3.10 venv` ?

Comment: @grumpyp I've installed ```python3-venv``` package. Not sure if it is Python3.10 or not.

Comment: @grumpyp ```venv``` is not a Python module, so it cannot be installed by ```pip```.

Comment: @MattDMo It should be at `/usr/bin/python3.10`. That's where mine is, though I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. And `/usr/bin` is in the default `PATH`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`python3.10 --version` will work.

[`python3-venv`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-venv) is for 3.8, so install `python3.10-venv`. For reference: [deadsnakes packages for 3.10 for Focal](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcepub/12770422/+listing-archive-extra).

Comment: This is the issue: the command to create a virtual environment is ```python3.10 -m venv *virtualenvname*```. So the ```venv``` part invokes ```python3.10-venv``` if it is installed?

Comment: @Omid Yes, though actually `python3.10-venv` isn't its own command, it's a package that installs the `venv` module for Python 3.10.

Answer (score 8):

So I was having the exact same problem. I figured out that I actually had to run "sudo apt-get install python3.10-full" instead of just "sudo apt-get install python3.10". I was then able to create a python3.10 virtual environment by executing "python3.10 -m venv virt".

Comment: I'm not sure we have ```apt-get install python3.10-full``` :(

Comment: There is a kerfuffle currently around what versions of Python you can install depending on your Ubuntu version. **Deadsnakes** is a repository which allows to install Python versions not available in the standard repos. I had already added **deadsnakes** to my repo list, so that I can `apt-get install python3.10-full`, which would indeed include `python3.10-venv`.

Comment: Sorry @OmidShojaee. I forgot to mention after seeing @Lenormju comment. You may need to add the **deadsnakes** repository to ubuntu so that you can issue `apt-get install python3.10-full`

Comment: Is there a way to go about doing this without adding the deadsnakes ppa?

Comment: @fatbringer i think if you have ubuntu 22.04 LTS, you should now be able to install python3.10 as it should be included in ubuntu's repos now. i could be wrong. try running 'apt-cache search python3.10' and if it's listed, then you should be able to install it without adding the deadsnakes PPA.

Comment: @RandyTang ah ok my ubuntu 22.04 actually has python 3.10. But i was trying to install the python3.10 venv.

Comment: @fatbringer yeah as long as you have python3.10, you can create a virtual environment by issuing 'python3.10 -m venv _name_of_virt_env_'

Comment: @RandyTang ok i got it. I suppose this was just recently added. Thanks so much!

Comment: And now I can create virtual environments with `python3.10 -m venv venv`, thanks.